# Apple Numbers program, weird thing with unix time code formula

Tags: numbers

Hi I have applied the unix time code formula

```
=(((A1/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)+(-5/24)
```

And it works! But the result I get on my column only shows the date and not the time. Does anyone know how to fix this? I attached an image to show what happens.

Thanks for your time.

The box on the top is the formula, the box on the bottom left is the "Formula Result" but the box in the row is the actual result I get.

I want the timecode too not just the date to appear in the rows.

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your problem please mark as such so that others who look for a similar solution get help too. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

@Ashley is correct.  For Numbers 3, Use the cell format to display the date and time the way you wish.  I pasted in your formula in the cell B2 below:

[image: Date formating in Numbers 3]
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Numbers '09 has a drop-down menu to specify the way that the time is shown in a Date and Time cell format.  The default in this situation seems to be None, but you can change it, as I show in the screenshot.

[image: Formatting Date and Time in Numbers '09]

From your screenshot, however, I think you are using a newer version of Numbers.  I don't know where this setting is in that version, sorry.

One more thing: I think the last part of your formula `+(-5/24)` is perhaps correcting for a local timezone difference from UTC.  I'm not sure, but you may need to change this when daylight savings time stops or starts: worth making a note to check this on that date.